# trouble getting my create-react-app to render on heroku

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, deployment, create-react-app

I have my react-app working totally fine on my localhost server, and I tried deploying it onto Heroku. However when I go to my app address I got from Heroku I am met with a blank page. None of the components or anything is being rendered. Any ideas why? I will post my server.js and App.js below or if there is anything else I can post to help figure this out let me know. Am I just linking something wrong so the components aren't being included in my builds index.html or is something else happening?

```js
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'; 
import "./styles.css";
import Home from './Home';
import Locations from './Locations';
import ContactForm from './Contact';
import NoMatch from './NoMatch';
import AboutUs from './AboutUs';
import Menu from './Menu';
import { NavigationBar } from './components/NavBar';


function App() {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <NavigationBar />
      
      
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
            <Route path="/locations" component={Locations} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={ContactForm} />
            <Route path="/menu" component={Menu} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>  
      
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 });

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)
```

Any help would be appreciated. You can look at the deployed page by going to https://desolate-river-56657.herokuapp.com/ if that helps at all as well. The only other thing I can think would be causing this is a wrong file structure where the components just aren't being included or something like that.

Comment: No errors in console?

Comment: i have a firebase error that i was going to work through afterwards. would that have any effect on my front-end being displayed though?

Answer (score 0):

if you are deploying your backend and frontend together then you need to write heroko post build script in backend package.json

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix ../FRONTEND FOLDER_NAME && npm run build --prefix npm start --prefix ../FRONTEND FOLDER_NAME"
```